# Spring Data JPA Proxies for interface projection not serializable to Redis

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-jpa

I'm attempting to store the results of a Repository query to a Redis cache, and running into the following error:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: Cannot construct instance of `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (byte[])"["java.util.ArrayList",[{"@class":"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173","busDate":"2022-09-12","vendorMasterAccount":"emily@emilylark.com","vendor":"btlife","affiliate":"5w1ft3bg","itemNo":null,"amount":158.55,"netAmount":null,"affAmount":null,"saleCount":null},{"@class":"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173","busDate":"2022-09-16","vendorMasterAccount":"emily@emilylark.com","vendor":"btlife","affiliate":"5w1ft3bg","itemNo":null,"amount":51.58,"netAmount":null,"affAmount":null,"saleCount":null},{"@class":"com.sun.proxy."[truncated 191979 bytes]; line: 1, column: 61] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (byte[])"["java.util.ArrayList",[{"@class":"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173","busDate":"2022-09-12","vendorMasterAccount":"emily@emilylark.com","vendor":"btlife","affiliate":"5w1ft3bg","itemNo":null,"amount":158.55,"netAmount":null,"affAmount":null,"saleCount":null},{"@class":"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173","busDate":"2022-09-16","vendorMasterAccount":"emily@emilylark.com","vendor":"btlife","affiliate":"5w1ft3bg","itemNo":null,"amount":51.58,"netAmount":null,"affAmount":null,"saleCount":null},{"@class":"com.sun.proxy."[truncated 191979 bytes]; line: 1, column: 61] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:130)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.DefaultRedisElementReader.read(DefaultRedisElementReader.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext$SerializationPair.read(RedisSerializationContext.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.deserializeCacheValue(RedisCache.java:280)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.lookup(RedisCache.java:94)
    at org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractValueAdaptingCache.get(AbstractValueAdaptingCache.java:58)
    at com.clickbank.clientanalytics.components.WebFluxCache.lambda$lookupWithMetrics$3(WebFluxCache.java:54)
    at reactor.cache.CacheMono.lambda$null$4(CacheMono.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2193)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2067)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(MonoSubscribeOn.java:126)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (byte[])"["java.util.ArrayList",[{"@class":"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173","busDate":"2022-09-12","vendorMasterAccount":"emily@emilylark.com","vendor":"btlife","affiliate":"5w1ft3bg","itemNo":null,"amount":158.55,"netAmount":null,"affAmount":null,"saleCount":null},{"@class":"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173","busDate":"2022-09-16","vendorMasterAccount":"emily@emilylark.com","vendor":"btlife","affiliate":"5w1ft3bg","itemNo":null,"amount":51.58,"netAmount":null,"affAmount":null,"saleCount":null},{"@class":"com.sun.proxy."[truncated 191979 bytes]; line: 1, column: 61] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1615)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1077)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1332)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:331)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:199)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:166)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:132)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:99)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:195)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:710)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:292)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:249)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:120)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromArray(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:53)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:193)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:710)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:68)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4526)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3529)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:150)
```

It seems to be an issue with Jackson not knowing how to serialize proxied instances of the interface.

Repository:

```
public interface AccountSalesHealthRepository extends CrudRepository<AccountSalesHealth, String> {
    @Query(
            value = "select vendor_master_account as vendorMasterAccount" +
                    "     , vendor" +
                    "     , affiliate" +
                    "     , bus_date         as busDate" +
                    "     , sum(sale_amount) as amount " +
                    "from mv_ca_account_sales_health " +
                    "where vendor_master_account = :vendorMasterAccount" +
                    "  and bus_date >= :start" +
                    "  and bus_date <= :end " +
                    "group by 1, 3, 2, 4",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    Collection<AccountSalesHealthDto> getGrossSalesByAffiliate(@Param("vendorMasterAccount") String vendorMasterAccount, @Param("start") String start, @Param("end") String end);
```

Entity model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mv_ca_account_sales_health")
public class AccountSalesHealth {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
}
```

DTO interface:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"busDate", "vendorMasterAccount", "vendor", "affiliate", "itemNo", "amount", "netAmount"})
public interface AccountSalesHealthDto {
    String getVendorMasterAccount();

    String getVendor();

    String getBusDate();

    String getAffiliate();

    String getItemNo();

    Double getAmount();

    Double getAffAmount();

    Double getNetAmount();

    Integer getSaleCount();
}
```

Is there any way to specify the way to create these or otherwise influence the serialization behavior?

Comment: Don't use a projection but a proper DTO so you don't need the proxy.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Found any solution?